# Next.js 14 router.push actin differently in production and development mode

Tags: typescript, next.js14

I am using routing in next version 14, and I have a simple back to home button

```
"use client";
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const BackToHomeButton = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    router.push('/');
  };

  return (
    <button
      className="back-to-home-button"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      Back to Home
    </button>
  );
};

export default BackToHomeButton;
```

The button works fine when I do npm run build followed by npm run start however, when I try to use the button with development mode by typing npm run dev, then when the button is clicked, nothing happens

Does anyone know why the button might be reacting differently in different mode?
Just so it helps, the file structure is

```
src
 |_ app
     |_(Home)
         |_page.tsx
         |_layout.tsx
     |_experience
        |_[id]
            |_page.tsx
            |_layout.tsx <- BacktoHome button is imported here
 |_ components
     |_BacktoHomeButton
```

P.S. Also to see if there was any other error, I have tried to directly include the button on both page.tsx and layout.tsx however even for both cases it didnt work.

Comment: Ok so the problem was having the root page inside the route-group (Home) now I just need to know how I can not apply the root layout to the experience page and allow it to just have its own layout